# ExcelJS: "Uncaught EvalError: 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content" in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, content-security-policy, exceljs

I have deployed Angular Application that uses ExcelJS library on IIS server. My current security policy forces me to return below header in IIS Http Response

content-security-policy: script-src 'self';img-src 'self'

With this setting, angular app is not loading and giving following error.

exceljs.js:87162 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

Is there any way to override Http Response security Policy. I tried to add content security policy using

But it did not work.

Could anyone please suggest how to run ExcelJS with strict content security policy?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved by using below Steps:

First include import `regenerator-runtime` before `exceljs` import

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import { Workbook } from 'exceljs';
```

2nd go to `tsconfig.json` and include bare version of `exceljs` path after `"compileOnSave":false`

```
"exceljs": [
        "node_modules/exceljs/dist/exceljs.bare.min.js"
]
```